# Initial ideal of k-th power of an ideal

Tags: monomial-ideals, ac.commutative-algebra

Hi,

Let $I$ be an ideal in a polynomial ring $S = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Fix a term order on 
$S$ (e.g. a lexicographic order) and let $in(I)$ denote the initial ideal of $I$, that is, the monomial ideal generated by all the initial terms of elements of $I$.

It is clear that for any $k > 0$ one has $in(I)^k \subset in(I^k)$, with equality if $I$ itself is a monomial ideal.

- Is there an example of $I$ where for large $k$, the quotient $in(I^k) / in(I)^k$ is NOT finite dimensional (over $k$)?
- Is there a "good" sufficient condition on $I$ and the term order to guarantee that for large 
  $k$, $in(I^k) / in(I)^k$ is always finite dimensional? Clearly if $I$ is primary or is a monomial ideal this is the case.

Comment: Hello. Can you show the proof or a reference for the case when $I$ is a primary (or prime) ideal? Thank you.

Comment: Youngsu: It follows from the following observations: $I$ is primary iff $S/I$ is finite dimensional as a vector space over $k$. Since 
$\dim(S/I) = \dim(S/ in(I))$ it follows that $in(I)$ is also primary. 
Now for any $k > 0$, $in(I)^k$ should be primary. Thus $S/in(I)^k$ is finite dimensional which implies that $in(I^k) / in(I)^k$ is also finite dimensional.

Comment: Here by "primary" I mean m-primary where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal generated by $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Nevertheless if $\mathfrak{n}$ is another maximal ideal and $I$ is $\mathfrak{n}$-primary then $S/I$ is finite dimensional over ${\bf k}$.  

Comment: Kiumars: Hi. I thought by primary you meant an ideal which is primary to an arbitrary prime ideal. Now, it is clear to me too. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry Youngsu for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Hal Schenck kindly provided a counter-example to the claim in question.
Consider the twisted cubic: (the code is in Macaulay)

o3 I = ideal (- y^2  + x*z, - y*z + x*w, - z^2  + y*w)

i4 : J = ideal leadTerm I

o4 = ideal (z^2 , y*z, y^2 )

i5 : hilbertPolynomial coker gens ideal leadTerm I^2

o5 = - 16*P  + 9*P
            0      1

i6 : hilbertPolynomial coker gens ideal leadTerm J^2

o6 = - 20*P_0  + 10*P_1

So, the quotient is actually positive dimensional.